# Displaying the OS name/version and the browser name/version on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to display the OS name and version on the page with JavaScript?

I am currently using this:

```
function detectOSAndBrowser() {
var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
var browserName  = navigator.appName;
var nameOffset,verOffset,ix;

// In Opera, the true version is after "Opera" or after "Version"
if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Opera"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Opera";
}
// In MSIE, the true version is after "MSIE" in userAgent
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("MSIE"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Internet Explorer";
}
// In Chrome, the true version is after "Chrome" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Chrome"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Google Chrome";
}
// In Safari, the true version is after "Safari" or after "Version" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Safari"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Safari";
}
// In Firefox, the true version is after "Firefox" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Firefox"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Mozilla Firefox";
}
// In most other browsers, "name/version" is at the end of userAgent 
else if ( (nameOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ')+1) < (verOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf('/')) ) 
{
 browserName = nAgt.substring(nameOffset,verOffset);

 if (browserName.toLowerCase()==browserName.toUpperCase()) {
  browserName = navigator.appName;
 }
}
var OSName = "unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) { 
OSName="Windows";
}
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) {
OSName="Mac OS X";
}
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) {
OSName="UNIX";
}
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) {
OSName="Linux";
}
if (OSName!=="unknown OS") {
$('#device').html('You\'re using '+browserName+'<br /><div id="OS">on a '+OSName+' computer.</div>');
}
if (OSName=="unknown OS") {
$('#device').html('We were unable to detect your OS and/or browser.');
}
```

It works, but I want to display the version of the OS and Browser too. This is how it looks right now when I view it:

[image: Screenshot]

How could I make it display the version of the browser and OS also?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried). What don't you understand about the problem? Do you understand how the code you posted actually works now?

Comment: You are presenting a copy+pasted script that already contains pointers like `navigator.appVersion`. You could experiment with that, or e.g. look into the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.navigator). (How did this get *two upvotes*?)

Comment: @Pekka Actually, I edited the code and i didn't simply copy and paste it. I did a lot of extra stuff to it and I'm not a JavaScript expert. _If you are, good for you._ But I don't know how to do this, which is why I asked here. I tried searching Google with no results.

Comment: @Brian I kind of understand it, but I don't know how to get the actual version (just the simple version, like in my case "Chrome 13") with `navigation.appVersion` because `navigation.appVersion` returns a long & ugly string.

Comment: @Nathan then *mention* those things. It's an essential part of the question. Without it, this looks like a "do my work for me" request

Comment: @Nathan - `navigator.userAgent` returns a "long and ugly" string as well; the code above is then parsing that string to extract information. That is what you have to do. You'll need to look at each string, and figure out how to reliably extract what you're looking for.

Comment: @Brian ok, I will try doing something like that.

Comment: @Nathan - possibly, yes - if the version is consistently at the same index like the name is. Or, you may need to use [regular expressions](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev.shtml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Quirksmode.org is hosting a very well-thought-through script named [`BrowserDetect`.](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)

It has specialized search strings to extract the *real* version number for all major browsers.

> You're using Chrome 13 on Windows!

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a great script.

Answer (score 1):

To detect the version of the browser, you can use [jQuery.browser.version](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/#jQuery-browser-version2).

Comment: I get `The version number of the rendering engine your browser uses is: 535.1` for Chrome 13