# browser & platform detection by using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, browser, platform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying the OS name/version and the browser name/version on the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370200/displaying-the-os-name-version-and-the-browser-name-version-on-the-page)

Does anybody know is there any template for assigning a specific CSS file to a specific browser and platform by using Javascript?

Comment: The better approach is to use _feature_ detection rather than _browser_ detection. Take a look at [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

Comment: There probably is, but since conditional statements are already built into most browsers, not many people uses a javascript solution for switching stylesheets.

Comment: Yes, there are possibilities to do that. But: Don't do it! Use feature detection instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jQuery to detect the browser, is the fastest way in my opinion http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/ and then just create or update your link tag for the css (like you would change ant DOM node)

```
<link id="my_css" src="" />
```

in jQuery:

```
$('#my_css').attr({src:"my_css_for"+$.browser+".css"})
```

also if you want to add css for diffrent ie versions you can do this in the html:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 1):

you should use google before you ask questions like this:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html