# How to get the OS name and version with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, operating-system, user-agent, navigator

I am creating an object to make it easier to access browser/system information by calling a function. One of those functions accesses the operating system name and version and returns a value.

```js
const Sys = {
  // retrieves the operating system
  OS: function () {
    // function body
  }
  // other functions...
}
```

I don't know how to go about getting the information I need. I did find a similar question on Stack Overflow, but it didn't get the correct information. For example, if I am running on a Windows 10 Pro 32-bit, I want the output to be `"Windows 10 Pro 32-bit"`. I'm guessing I have to use the `navigator` object, but other than that I really don't know anything else. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the operating system version using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript)

Comment: @CalvinNunes No, I tried using that solution but I didn't get all of the information, only some of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying the OS name/version and the browser name/version on the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370200/displaying-the-os-name-version-and-the-browser-name-version-on-the-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using [platform.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/platform) (see [demo](https://bestiejs.github.io/platform.js/)).

Identify user's browser:

```js
platform.os;
// => OS X 10.15.6 (in my case)
```

Or parse a userAgent string.

```js
let info = platform.parse("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.1 Safari/605.1.15");

info.name;
// => Safari

info.version;
// => 14.0.1

info.description;
// => Safari 14.0.1 on OS X 10.15.6
```

Comment: Would I be able to use Platform.js without having npm or Node.js installed?

Comment: It's a browser library. Just include it in your HTML file with a `<script src="path to platform.js"></script>` tag and you should be good.

Comment: Without a package manager, you can download the script from github: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bestiejs/platform.js/master/platform.js

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' Thanks! I will test it, and if this works I will accept your answer.

Comment: Seems like the library is no longer maintained.